# How to programmatically select a angular bootstrap nav tab from a component class

Tags: angular, navbar, ng-bootstrap

Hi how can I obtain a reference to a ngbNav ng-bootstrap component in my component class so I can select some tab programmatically?
This doesnt work:

```
@ViewChild('nav') nav? : ElementRef<NgbNav>;
```

In my html template I have:

```
<ul ngbNav #nav="ngbNav" [(activeId)]="active" (navChange)="onNavChange($event)" class="nav-tabs">
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 3):

Your approach seems to work for me - I just needed to add a method to select the tab; you can call `this.nav.select(index);` to select the tab you require programatically (tabs indexes start from 1 rather than 0).

I've created a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dafjyw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnav-basic.ts) - click the button below the tabs to select the third tab. The code is:

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="selectTab()">Select Tab 3</button>
```

**TypeScript**

```
@ViewChild("nav") // Get a reference to the ngbNav
nav;

selectTab() {
    // Programatically select the third tab
    this.nav.select(3);
}
```